# My tkinter ui for logging into facebook doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm kinda new to learning python and wanted to make a UI for a program I got from the book I'm studying from. The program opens up Facebook on chrome and logs you in but doesn't work properly with the UI.

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Facebook(Frame):
    def __init__(self,window):

        Frame.__init__(self,window,padx=12,pady=12)

        window.title("FBGiriş")
        window.geometry("350x200+50+50")
        self.lab1 = Label(window, text="email adress: ", bg="grey", 
borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.lab1.place(x=20, y=40)
        self.lab2 = Label(window, text="password: ", bg="grey", 
borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.lab2.place(x=40, y=80)


       self.ent1 = Entry(window, bg="cyan", relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
       self.ent2 = Entry(window, bg="cyan", relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)

      self.ent1.place(x=140, y=40)
      self.ent2.place(x=140, y=80)

      self.gButton = Button(window, text="Login", relief=GROOVE, 
command=self.face, borderwidth=5, bg="red")
      self.gButton.place(x=260, y=120)

   def face(self):

       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
       self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
       self.fbLogin()

   def fbLogin(self):

       #self.face()
       driver = self.driver

       self.ent1 = str(self.ent1)
       self.ent2 = str(self.ent2)
       username = self.ent1

       password = self.ent2

       emailid = 'email'
       passid = 'pass'
       loginid = "loginbutton"
       logoclass = "_48pw"
       emailbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_id(emailid))
       passbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_id(passid))
       loginButton = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_id(loginid))
       emailbox.click()
       emailbox.clear()
       emailbox.send_keys(username)

       passbox.click()
       passbox.clear()
       passbox.send_keys(password)


       loginButton.click()

       WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_class_name(logoclass))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    app = Facebook(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

The UI opens up facebook on chrome when i type my email and password in textboxes and then click Login. But no matter what i type in the Entry textboxes, it types random numbers on facebook:

**Screenshots:**

Input

[image]

Intended Output

[image]

Current (Incorrect) Output

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post an example of what the intended output should be.

Comment: @ZacharyEspiritu I guess i can't directly put images here so
the input: https://imgur.com/a/MiXPU
the output: https://imgur.com/a/2dCZB
But instead of what is intended(example@hotmail.com and password), the program types random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random numbers are references to instances of the `tkinter` `Entry`s `self.ent1` and `self.ent2`. What you need is the content of those entries, you need to call the `get` method on the entries to obtain their content.

Change this:

```
username = self.ent1
password = self.ent2
```

To:

```
username = self.ent1.get()
password = self.ent2.get()
```

Also, calling `str` on an instance of a `Tkinter` widget won't give you any useful output, hence the following code is not helpful:

```
self.ent1 = str(self.ent1)
self.ent2 = str(self.ent2)
```

You also seem to have some indentation errors here is the full code, which I was able to log into Facebook with:

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Facebook(Frame):
    def __init__(self,window):
        Frame.__init__(self,window,padx=12,pady=12)

        window.title("FBGiris")
        window.geometry("350x200+50+50")
        self.lab1 = Label(window, text="email adress: ", bg="grey", borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.lab1.place(x=20, y=40)
        self.lab2 = Label(window, text="password: ", bg="grey", borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.lab2.place(x=40, y=80)


        self.ent1 = Entry(window, bg="cyan", relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
        self.ent2 = Entry(window, bg="cyan", relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)

        self.ent1.place(x=140, y=40)
        self.ent2.place(x=140, y=80)

        self.gButton = Button(window, text="Login", relief=GROOVE, command=self.face, borderwidth=5, bg="red")
        self.gButton.place(x=260, y=120)


    def face(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
        self.fbLogin()

    def fbLogin(self):
        #self.face()
        driver = self.driver

        username = self.ent1.get()
        password = self.ent2.get()

        emailid = 'email'
        passid = 'pass'
        loginid = "loginbutton"
        logoclass = "_48pw"
        emailbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailid))
        passbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passid))
        loginButton = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginid))

        emailbox.click()
        emailbox.clear()
        emailbox.send_keys(username)

        passbox.click()
        passbox.clear()
        passbox.send_keys(password)

        loginButton.click()

        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
        driver.find_element_by_class_name(logoclass))   

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    app = Facebook(root)
    app.mainloop()
```